# How to use same adapter in two activity in different ways

Tags: android

Is it possible to call same adapter in two activity for different different work
Here is my RecyclerAdapter:
Only difference when calling from two activity is in this line: From Activity1.java it is:

```
        holder.Name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
```

And from Activity2.java

```
        holder.Name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getVehicle());
```

All other code is same how can I use same adapter for different different work.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Contact> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> arrayList){

    this.arrayList= arrayList;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.Name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    int sync_status = arrayList.get(position).getSync_status();
    if(sync_status== DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK){
        holder.Sync_Status.setImageResource(R.drawable.success);

    }
    else {
        holder.Sync_Status.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopwatch);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView Sync_Status;
    TextView Name;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Sync_Status=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSync);
        Name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Contact> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
private int whichActivity;

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> arrayList, int activity){
    whichActivity = activity;
    this.arrayList= arrayList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(whichActivity == 0) {
        holder.Name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    }
    else {
        holder.Name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getVehicle());
    }
    int sync_status = arrayList.get(position).getSync_status();
    if(sync_status== DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK){
        holder.Sync_Status.setImageResource(R.drawable.success);

    }
    else {
        holder.Sync_Status.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopwatch);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView Sync_Status;
    TextView Name;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Sync_Status=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSync);
        Name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    }
}
}
```

Try this code.  Now when you create your RecyclerAdapter in **Activity1 call new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList, 0)** and when you create your RecyclerAdapter in **Activity2 call new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList, 1)**.  You are just passing a variable into the constructor so your adapter knows which activity it is in and can run through different logic depending on the activity.